# Multiple default gateways warning

Tags: networking, ip, gateway

I'm a little out of my depth on this problem here.  I'm getting the warning about multiple default gateways.  I'm not understanding where the multiple gateways is coming from.  I've gathered the following information

Results from route print
[image]

Properties from the IP4
[image]

And finally a list of my connections
[image]

Comment: When do you get the warning?  And what does ipconfig show?

Comment: I get it when clicking ok on the properties window.

Comment: I assume `ipconfig` shows multiple default gateways?  And I assume you mean when you click "ok" on the properties window after manually setting some of the network properties?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Since both gateways show the same IP address should I ignore the warning?

Comment: Hard to answer without `ipconfig /all` output . . . generally, that warning isn't a big deal, unless you've got some unusual network needs (e.g. multi-home).  If things are working for you, you can probably safely ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it typing:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork (actually I disabled it from the control panel, but I guess this command does the same)
```

My hypothesis / explanation:

hostednetwork is the wireless VIRTUAL network. Not sure why, it was configured with the same IP than the WiFi adapter. Then it was stopped (or it crashed!). Restarting it cleaned that duplicate ips problem.

Notice that any network device could have the duplicate IP. Check the manual assigned IPs of the other network devices too.

Anyway, it is just an hypotheis. But it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have a persistent route added, check Persistant routes table in the image that you placed, I do not remember exactly how to remove it but someone else added this route for you in the past with the command "route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.15.1 -persistent"

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer, though it could be helpful information. Please do some research to find how to remove the unnecessary route, then edit your answer to be a complete solution.

Answer (score -1):

On two different interfaces getevey. The message should appear.

[image: two different interfaces getevey]

Comment: When I saw that I figured because they both had the same IP I was ok, but you're saying that because there are two of them that's causing the problem?  If I disable the second connection would that solve the problem?

Comment: This shouldn't matter . . . all this shows is that each interface can be used to get to 0.0.0.0, with a preference of the 192.168.15.134 interface since it has a lower metric.  When going over that interface, the gateway 192.168.15.1 is used . . .

Comment: @Jhorra If the locks are in the settings of two different network cards, an error will occur. Either remove all gateways with network cards by default and add them as permanent routes from the command route.